# Emberjs {{each}} with computed properties don't work

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an Ember.js ArrayController and I'm trying to create a computed property that generates the sum of visits, but I'm stuck:

**Controller with sort array**

```
App.SpreadsheetController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   sortProperties: ['visits'],
   sortAscending: false, 

   allVisits: function() {
      var visits = this.get('content.@each.visits').toArray(); 
      visits.forEach(function(val) {
         // sum all visits
      );
      return visits;
   }.property('content.@each.visits'),

   actions: {
      orderAsc: function (){
        this.set('sortAscending', true);
      },

      orderDesc: function (){
         this.set('sortAscending', false);
      },
}
```

});

**index.html**

```
Without each: {{allVisits}} //show
    {{#each}}
      {{allVisits}} //don't show
    {{/each}}
```

why don't show all visits within each? any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It would have to be

```
{{#each allVisits}}
      {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

since the local context in the `{{each}}` loop is the current element that is being iterated over, which will not have an allVisits property

Comment: I'm try:


Without each: {{allVisits}} //show
    {{#each}}
      {{site_name}}-
      {{#each allVisits}}
        {{this}} //dont work
      {{/each}}

    {{/each}}

Comment: I don't understand you last comment - where does `site_name` come from?

Comment: I need show allvisits aside visits and site_name..
Example output:
siteA.com - visits:1000 - all site visits:10000000
siteB.com - visits:3000 - all site visits:10000000

Comment: What's the model for `visit`?

Comment: **App.Spreadsheet** = DS.Model.extend({
    site_name: DS.attr('string'),
    visits: DS.attr('number'),// site_visits
});

Comment: Also, do you have a variable number of sites or only 2?

Comment: This might take a bit of effort - Any chance you could put together a jsFiddle or jsBin?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution that works for me

```
{{#each}}
      {{controller.allVisits}}
{{/each}}
```

Thanks by the way